# How do you get text to copy to clipboard when clicking on an image?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to copy text to the clipboard when clicking on an image but after many failed attempts, I'm stuck. Here's where I am now:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="text which you want copy" id="myInput" hidden>
<img src="nameofimage.jpg" onclick="myFunction()"></img>
```

Does anyone have a solution?

vanowm's solution below works perfectly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Comment: It works fine on macbook pro and chrome. It actually copied the text "text which you want copy" to my clipboard. I actually pasted that in.

Comment: Maybe you want to read: web.dev/async-clipboard Under "Security and permissions" you will find "As with many new APIs, the Clipboard API is only supported for pages served over HTTPS.."

Comment: vanowm's answer works perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can temporary unhide the input field:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.hidden = false;
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  copyText.hidden = true;
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="text which you want copy" id="myInput" hidden>
<img src="nameofimage.jpg" onclick="myFunction()">
```